# jQuery Carousel plugin scroll to first item on click

Tags: jquery, html, plugins, button, carousel

I am using this jQuery plugin: http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm to create a vertical carousel.

I would like to do something similar to the pagination, where a button is clicked and the corresponding frame is scrolled to. But I want only one button. This button will come after the last frame, and it will read "back to top." When it is clicked, it will scroll to the first item in the carousel. Anyone know how I can easily trigger this event?

Comment: It's a shame you picked that plugin. I would have avoided it for two reasons: no documentation except for set-up, and there's no link to uncompressed source.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the following, which I think is what you're trying to achieve.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/skins/tango/skin.css" />


    <script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel(
    {
        vertical: true,
        scroll: 1
    });

    // Loop through all images and attach click action
    jQuery("#mycarousel img").each( function(index, element)
    {
        $(element).click( function()
        {
            jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel('scroll', index + 1);
        });
    });  
});

</script>
</head>

<body>

<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel jcarousel-skin-tango">
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/75/199481072_b4a0d09597_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/57/199481087_33ae73a8de_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/77/199481108_4359e6b971_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481143_3c148d9dd3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/72/199481203_ad4cdcf109_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481218_264ce20da0_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/69/199481255_fdfe885f87_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/60/199480111_87d4cb3e38_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/70/229228324_08223b70fa_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Helped me with what I needed to do +1

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the jquery scrollTo plugin:
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/localScroll/#section1

The link to download the plugin is on the right of that page.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need a plugin just for this. The functionality it there, I need to find how I can trigger it.